# trying to merge multiple array in a loop codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hey this Is a piece of code I have where I am getting result from the database and I am trying to combine all array I get from the database into one.
Here is the piece of code I am using

```
$result = array();
  foreach($invoices as $invoice){
     $result = $this->fee_page->readFeeRowsForInvoice($invoice['ORIG_ID']) ;
     $result += array_merge($result);
  }
```

The for each I am using is because my $invoices looks like this, 
[image] SO I need to get both the arrays into the result as 2 arrays but just with [0] and [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80HPL.jpg).

Comment: Please post your code, instead of image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code as follow.

```
$result = array();
  foreach($invoices as $invoice){
     $invoice_rows = $this->fee_page->readFeeRowsForInvoice($invoice['ORIG_ID']) ;
     $result[] = $invoice_rows;
  }
```

We don't use **+** sign to  merge two array. You simply add array values to other array using **[]**.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = array();  $append = array(); 

   foreach($invoices as $invoice){

     $append = $this->fee_page->readFeeRowsForInvoice($invoice['ORIG_ID']) ;
     $result[]= $append;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use array_push() function instead of array_merge() like this

$result = array();
foreach($invoices as $invoice){

 $temp = $this->fee_page->readFeeRowsForInvoice($invoice['ORIG_ID']) ;
 array_push($result,$temp);

}
```

I hope this will work for you.